# Javascript Click Function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I'm working on a little weather app. The last thing I'm trying to do is making the big weather Icon clickable to switch the ° unit between Fahrenheit and Celsius.

My code doesn't seem to do anything. I would appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction or give me a hint, how I should approach something like that.

```js
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    ausgabeLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var jsonURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&units=imperial&APPID=';
  getWeather(jsonURL, lon, lat);
}

function getWeather(jsonURL, lon, lat) {

  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
    var tempFahr = json['main']['temp'];
    var tempCels = Math.floor(((tempFahr - 32) / 1.8) * 100) / 100;
    var iconID = json['weather'][0]['id'];
    var city = json['name'];
    ausgabeLocation.innerHTML = city;
    ausgabeTemp.innerHTML = tempCels + "°C";
    $("#iconShow").html("<i class='owf owf-" + iconID + "'></i>");
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getLocation();
  var unitSwitch = false;
  $('.swapUnit').click(function() {
    if (unitSwitch) {
      $(this).html(tempCels + " '°C'");
      unitSwitch = false;
    } else {
      $(this).html(tempFahr + " '°F'");
      unitSwitch = true;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1 id="ausgabeLocation" class="text-center"></h1>
  <div id="cont-center" class="box container-fluid box-shadow">


    <span id="iconShow" class="icon1"></span>
    <div id="ausgabeTemp" class="swapUnit">
      </h2>
    </div>

</body>
```

You can look at the whole thing here: http://codepen.io/ttimon/pen/QEPZJW

Thank you.

edit: Ok I changed some things and I have it working now. See code below. The only thing I am wondering is if I could have done it without using global variables.

Javascript

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        ausgabeLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  getWeather(lon, lat);
}

function getWeather(lon,lat){
        var jsonURL =  'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&units=metric&APPID=af0761262e54344b40ea5757a84f9e81';
        $.getJSON(jsonURL,function(json){
          var temp = json['main']['temp'];
          var iconID = json['weather'][0]['id'];
          var city = json['name'];
          writeStuff(temp,iconID,city);
          });
         function writeStuff(temp,iconID,city){
           window.tempFahr = Math.floor(temp*9/5+32);
           window.tempCels = Math.floor(temp*100/100);
           ausgabeLocation.innerHTML = city;
            ausgabeTemp.innerHTML = tempCels + "°C";
          $("#iconShow").html("<i class='owf owf-"+iconID+"'></i>");
         }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getLocation();
  var unitSwitch = false;
  $(document).on('click','#iconShow',function () {
                if(unitSwitch===true){
      ausgabeTemp.innerHTML = tempCels + '°C';
      unitSwitch = false;
    }else{
      ausgabeTemp.innerHTML = tempFahr + '°F';
      unitSwitch = true;
    }
            });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<h1 id="ausgabeLocation" class="text-center"></h1>
<div id="cont-center" class="box container-fluid box-shadow">


  <span id="iconShow" class="icon1" ></span>
  <div id="ausgabeTemp" class="swapUnit"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your problem is variable scope. You click delegate has no concept of `tempCels` or `tempFahr` because they are declared within the scope of `getWeather`

Comment: @IanBrindley Thank you for your feedback. How would I go about fixing this? How can I make these variables accesible for the click function?

Comment: @IanBrindley Hey thanks for your tip. I have it working now. See my edit in the original post. I just have one follow up question. Would this be possible without using global variables or is it ok to use global variables here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Second problem is no correct closed tag . So this code

```
<div id="ausgabeTemp" class="swapUnit"></h2>
```

replace to

```
<div id="ausgabeTemp" class="swapUnit"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page requested an
>   insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=32.647371&lon=35.42155100000001&units=imperial&APPID=af0761262e54344b40ea5757a84f9e81'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

HTTPS is available only in Professional and Enterprise accounts. In Free account this feature is not available. Please, read more http://openweathermap.org/price

Comment: this is not my problem though. the api call works fine for me on firefox. i've had problems with chrome though. might be the same for you. thanks for looking at it anyway!